# Can't get colour of div to change using loop / switch statement combination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple memory game, where a shape flashes up on screen x number of times and the user has to remember the colour.

I'm trying to use a loop combined with a switch statement to change the colour on each iteration. However, the colour does not change and I'm stuck.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var colorArray = []; // stores which colours have been generated

var changeColour = function(){
var generateShape = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) // Generates a number from 0-4

switch (generateShape){
            case 0:
                $('#shapeDiv').css('background-color','black');
                $('#shapeDiv').fadeOut(500);
                colorArray.push('B');
                break;
            case 1:
                $('#shapeDiv').css('background-color','red');
                $('#shapeDiv').fadeOut(500);
                colorArray.push('R');
                break;
            case 2:
                $('#shapeDiv').css('background-color','yellow');
                $('#shapeDiv').fadeOut(500);
                colorArray.push('Y');
                break;
            case 3:
                $('#shapeDiv').css('background-color','blue');
                $('#shapeDiv').fadeOut(500);
                colorArray.push('BL');
                break;
            case 4:
                $('#shapeDiv').css('background-color','pink');
                $('#shapeDiv').fadeOut(500);
                colorArray.push('P');
                break;
        };
}

$('#subbutton').click(function(){

        // make shape appear 5 times with random colour
    while (colorArray.length<5){

        $('#shapeDiv').fadeIn(500);
        changeColour();

    };
})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is, your while loop runs and creates the random numbers. But `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are asynchron. The loop is done in far under 500ms and the `generateShape` as the last generated value which is then used in the `switch`.

I cant think of an easy change to your code to avoiding this. I think you will have to work out an other solution with the asynchron nature of annimations in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using an interval:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var interval = 0;
var colorArray = [];

var changeColour = function(){
    console.log(colorArray);

    var generateShape = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) // Generates a number from 0-4

    switch (generateShape){
                case 0:
                    $('#shapeDiv').css('background-color','black');
                    colorArray.push('B');
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $('#shapeDiv').css('background-color','red');
                    colorArray.push('R');
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $('#shapeDiv').css('background-color','yellow');
                    colorArray.push('Y');
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $('#shapeDiv').css('background-color','blue');
                    colorArray.push('BL');
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $('#shapeDiv').css('background-color','pink');
                    colorArray.push('P');
                    break;
            };
    if (colorArray.length > 5){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
};

$('#subbutton').click(function(){
    interval = setInterval(changeColour,1000);
})
});
```